# FFMpeg very slow on i3 Windows machine

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, ffmpeg, truecrypt

I have a mystery. I am using ffmpeg.exe to convert videos to frames. On most machines I get very good speed. On an i7 I get 144fps. On an old Core 2 Duo machine I get 75fps.

But weirdly on an fairly new i3 (4 core) I get 30fps or less.

I have run these tests using exactly the same version of ffmpeg and the same video file.

All machines are Windows 7, all have 4 GB ram. I'm trying to understand why the i3 is so slow for FFMpeg. All other applications seem to run fine. No memory problems I know of. The virus scanner is the same on all machines - MS Security Essentials.

The only difference I can think of is the i3 machine has truecrypt. But I don't see why it would have an impact.

What am I not thinking of? Graphics card?

Comment: which Core i3 is it? Those aren't very fast.

Comment: I'll be able to check the exact model in the morning. But I would have thought i3 is faster than an old Core 2 Duo. I clock the i3 at less than half the speed of the Core 2 Duo, which seems unlikely.

Comment: Could you add the console output of the ffmpeg command? BTW the fps you get is very much process dependant. I'm usually getting 12fps or less with my 2 pass conversions to h264.

Comment: Command I'm using is ffmpeg.exe -i filename.avi temp\picture%d.jpg

Comment: The chip is an i3 2350M 2.3GHz 4 core. Apparently, it doesn't have hardware aes support so would that mean truecrypt would slow down ffmpeg?

Comment: We uninstalled truecrypt and it didn't make any difference. Odd.

Comment: Ok - I think we may have solved this. Last night the hard disk bricked. Laptop was only about a year old. So I'm going to write this whole thing off as dodgy hardware.